# Null Pointer Exception with Input Streams in android

Tags: android, audio, nullpointerexception, signal-processing, inputstream

```
private double [] readFile (InputStream _input) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream audioInput = new DataInputStream (new BufferedInputStream (_input));

    int musicLength = (int)(audioInput.available()/2.0);
    double [] music = new double [musicLength];

    int i = 0; 
    while (i < audioInput.available() && i < musicLength) {
        music[i] = (double)audioInput.readShort();
        i++;
    }

    audioInput.close();
    return music;
}
```

This code is part of a larger project I am working on, that involves DSP techniques to compare two audio signals. This code is supposed to return a double [] containing the raw data in an audio file (InputStream _input is a parameter that represents the result of a call to `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.audio_file)`, and is NOT null). However, when I run the code, I get a Null Pointer Exception. The relevant part of the stack trace is as follows:

```
03-12 22:24:57.818: W/System.err(8931): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 22:24:57.818: W/System.err(8931):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.getAssetRemainingLength(Native Method)
03-12 22:24:57.818: W/System.err(8931):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$300(AssetManager.java:36)
03-12 22:24:57.818: W/System.err(8931):     at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.available(AssetManager.java:552)
03-12 22:24:57.818: W/System.err(8931):     at com.ashwin.iSleep.AudioRecorder.readFile(AudioRecorder.java:88)
```

According to the stack trace, the exact error is at the call to `audioInput.available()`. From what I can tell, the problem is with the native method `AssetManager.getAssetRemainingLength()`. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Pl. check from where you are calling this function. If you are getting  null pointer do not call this function....

Answer (score 2):

Using [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/content/res/AssetManager.java#AssetManager), you can see that you gave `readFile` instance of `AssetInputStream` ( derived from InputStream ). `AssetInputStream.available` calls `getAssetRemainingLength` with member `mAsset` as param - and how we can see, for example, [here](http://source-android.frandroid.com/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_util_AssetManager.cpp), NullException is thrown if mAssert == 0. But in source from grepcode we can see that in constructor `AssetInputStream` we calls `getAssetLength` which verify is `mAsset` equal null too. It means that `mAsset` is nullified after `AssetInputStream` instance was created. You can see from same [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/content/res/AssetManager.java#AssetManager) page, that it happens when you close your `AssetInputStream` instance. So the answer is - you've closed `_input` before `readFile` method was called.

Answer (score 0):

I found there are two issues in the code

**1  You are not checking inputstream against null.**

**2 In efficient way of getting DataInoutStream from InpoutStream**

Why you are using the following code to convert inputstream to DatainoputSTream 
`DataInputStream audioInput = new DataInputStream (new BufferedInputStream (_input));`

In this code you are trying to get BufferrdInoutstream from inputstream and then from bufferred input stream you are trying to get Data inout Stream. Which is not necessary you can directly get DataInputStream from InputStream 
using the following code

`DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(_input);`

Comment: he said _(InputStream _input is a parameter that represents the result of a call to getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.audio_file), and is NOT null)_